# JavaScript InfoVis Toolkit Browser Support

Tags: javascript, toolkit, infovis

I'm using JavaScript InfoVis Toolkit in a project and need to compile documentation for browser support. Unfortunately I cannot find any official information on their website. Does anyone know what browsers and versions are officially supported (or compatible)?